# Django Markdown or WYSIWYG editor

Tags: django, wysiwyg, markdown

I have user generated context that extends multiple paragraphs.  I'd like to enable the user to create paragraphs, possibly change font-weight, but nothing too huge.

I've seen a tutorial which uses the Python-Markdown module.  Would anyone recommend this or should I just go with a WYSIWYG plugin?  I've seen plugins for the admin but have not yet seen it applied to a general Django template.

Thanks
Brendan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used django tiny-mce with tinymce in my comment app and is working. Defining plugins for this WYSIWYG editor is easy and comes only to  specifying name of plugin in settings.py and JS file.

Comment: Hi Chris, I started with Ckedit but that has a PIL dependency.  Unfortunately, I'm developing locally on a Win 64bit machine and PIL is a nightmare to install.  I'll give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: hmm, slight fail on my part.  I followed the installation/configuration but I'm experiencing a js failure ('tinyMCE_GZ is not defined').  I've copied the js file into the appropriate location. The documentation is scant

Comment: Make sure that You have well configured tinymce in settings.py.

Comment: Or better show something more of error code and/or of your settings code.

Answer (score 1):

MarkItUp! editor can help http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/
It have many rich features, includes django model class MarkupField(models.TextField), JS-settingynized editor's toolbar, etc.